# There are no body properties in Cinemachine's virtual camera

Tags: unity, camera, cinemachine

Why are there no [body properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.7/manual/CinemachineVirtualCameraBody.html) in Cinemachine's virtual camera?

Unity version: 2021.3.11f1

Cinemachine Version: 2.8.9

[image: Camera inspector showing no "body" property]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inspector is currently in Debug mode, which disables custom editor drawing code that components like Cinemachine use to present a friendlier user interface, and instead shows a raw dump of the internal state.

Try clicking the three-dot icon (⋮) in the top-right of your inspector window, and change to "Normal" mode:

[image: Inspector settings context menu]

That should make the more familiar / documented Cinemachine interface appear.